# Why does GetModuleHandleA return NULL?

Tags: visual-c++, dll

I am trying to load a custom resource (.rc) from a .dll but the `FindResource()` function always ends up returning `NULL`

This is my code trying to load the resource:

```
HINSTANCE FragDll;

FragDll = GetModuleHandleA((LPCSTR)"FragmentShaders.dll");

HRSRC FragResource = FindResource(FragDll, MAKEINTRESOURCE(StartMenu_frag), L"FRAGMENTSHADER");

if (FragResource)
{
    HGLOBAL FragLoadedResource = LoadResource(FragDll, FragResource);

    if (FragLoadedResource)
    {
        LPVOID FragLockedResource = LockResource(FragLoadedResource);

        if (FragLockedResource)
        {
            DWORD FragdwResourceSize = SizeofResource(FragDll, FragResource);

            if (0 != FragdwResourceSize)
            {
                // Use pLockedResource and dwResourceSize however you want
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`FragResource` for some reason always returns `NULL`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit:

I have done a breakpoint in visual studios to get more information:

[Values during runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AblKK.png)

EDIT:

If this method of loading resources from a .dll doesnt work, please then give another method of reading a resource (.rc) from a .dll.

Comment: `GetModuleHandle` does not return `NULL` but `FindResource` does. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Your screenshot shows that `FragDll` is in fact `NULL`, suggesting that `GetModuleHandle` has already failed.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: remove `(LPCSTR)` before `"FragmentShaders.dll"`

Comment: Removing (LPCSTR) doesnt do anything

Comment: I have tried both Microsoft C++ Compiler (v142) and LLVM Clang C++ Compiler, with all versions of C++ (C++20, C++17 and C++14). The only difference is that in C++14 `FragResource` is also `NULL`.

Comment: why `FragDll==0` after `GetModuleHandleA` ? why you not check this ?why `GetModuleHandleA` and `FindResourceW` ?

Comment: `FragDll` is the reason `FindResource` returns `NULL`. Do you know why `GetModuleHandleA((LPCSTR)"FragmentShaders.dll")` returns `NULL`?

Comment: There is more information on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/loadlibrary-and-afxloadlibrary?view=msvc-160 if this can help anyone.

Comment: because no module with name `"FragmentShaders.dll"` in your process

Comment: I have also tried replacing `"FragmentShaders.dll"` with the entire path to `"FragmentShaders.dll"`.

Comment: @RbMm I have `FragmentShaders.dll` placed in the same folder as my `.exe`.

Comment: nothing need try. if you not undertand what you do. if `GetModuleHandleA` return 0 - this mean - no dll with such name in your process. place of dll on disk here unrelated at all.

Comment: How do I add the `.dll` into my process then?

Comment: strange question. or static link to dll or load it via `LoadLibray[Ex]`

Comment: I am trying to load it via `LoadLibray[Ex]`.

Comment: I am new to vc++, so please explain as much as possible.

Comment: `GetModuleHandleA((LPCSTR)"FragmentShaders.dll");` -> `LoadLibraryW(L"FragmentShaders.dll");` - this is not related to vc++. this is related to windows/winapi

Comment: @RbMm, Do you know how to fix `FragDll` from retirning `NULL`?

Comment: i not undertand your question at all

Comment: The problem I am currently facing is that GetModuleHandleA returns NULL.

Comment: your problem have nothing common with your question. you dont know how load dll to process. dont know different between `GetModuleHandle` and `LoadLibrary`. different between A and W api.  you ask *why GetModuleHandleA returns NULL* - better ask yourself - why GetModuleHandleA must returns not NULL ?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that *FragmentShaders.dll* is loaded into your process, when executing the code?

Answer (score 0):

as others pointed out in the commentaries, the problem here is not that FragRessource is Null, it is null because FragDLL is null in the first place.

So we come to why is FragDLL null ?
As stated in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlea) of GetModuleHandleA : "The module must have been loaded by the calling process." Which means you have to load the module before retrieving his handle. You can do so using LoadLibraryExA (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa).
Hopes this helps